# Giftcards orders

Tags: event-observer, order-status, enterprise-1.14, gift-card

Trying to change the default state/status for orders that have only giftcard products.

Tried to find an event I can "observe" to achieve that but no luck. Also tried to change the setting in System > Configuration > Catalogue > Downloadable Product Options > Order Status but the same, no luck.

Anyone can point me in the right direction please? Any help is kindly appreciated.

Thanks

**LATER EDIT**

My bad, should've mentioned from the start I tried all the obvious, sales_order_place_after and related events, they don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got nowhere with events and after chatting with Vinai Kopp a few minutes decided that a good ol' rewrite is needed, since orders containing virtual products are a bit different than "normal" ones (they don't need shipments to be "completed").

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use **sales_order_place_after** event.you need to define below code in your module config.xml.

```
 <global>
     <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <OBSERVER_NAME>
                    <class>MODULE_FRONTNAME/NAME_OF_FILE_IN_MODEL_FOLDER</class>
                    <method>FUNCTION_NAME_FROM_ABOVE_CLASS</method>
                </OBSERVER_NAME>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
     </events>
 </global>
```

If you need to define file under following path:
**app/code/YOUR_CODEPOOL/NAMESPACE/YOUR_MODULE/Model/NAME_OF_FILE_IN_MODEL_FOLDER.php** Like Observer.php

In above file need to create function in observer.php with name which define in  tag of config.xml:

```
<?php
    public function sales_order_afterPlace($observer)
    {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $order_items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
      foreach ($order_items as $_item)
      {
          if($_item->getProductType()=='giftcard')
          {
             $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true);
             $order->save();
             break;
          }
      }
    }
?>
```

Following is a list a possible states:

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED

I hope this will help you.

Comment: yeah, forgot to mention that's the first thing I tried, to listen to `sales_order_place_after` - doesn't work.